# How to add multiple wpf listview under the same tab item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm currently developing a telephony windows application. I've three line toggle button (Line1, Line2, Line3) and a tab control with five tab items. In most of the tab items, I've a listview in each of them. For the first tab item, it is used to display the caller data. What I've done so far is when the caller calls in, the caller data is able to be displayed on the listview in the first tab item, regardless which line button is clicked. My problem is how can I make the line buttons have their own listview under the same tab item, without affect the rest of the tab items. For example, when Line1 button is toggled and caller calls in, the data will display on listview. When Line2 button is toggled and caller calls in, the data will display on "another" listview. When I click Line1 again, I still can see the caller's data when called into Line1.

Here's my listview in the first tab item:

```
<TabItem x:Name="CallTab" Header="Call" Width="56" Style="{StaticResource TabStyle}">
  <Grid Background="#FFEEEEEE">
    <ListView x:Name="CallTabLv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="164" Width="275" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFFBFCFC" BorderBrush="#FFCFCFCF" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,1,0,-1" Foreground="Black">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="KeyColumn" Header="Key" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Label}" />
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="ValueColumn" Header="Value" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
      <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
          <Style.Triggers> <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Label}" Value="Data"> <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/> </DataTrigger> <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Label}" Value="Line?"> <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/> </DataTrigger> </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

Is there anyway to add multiple listview under the same tab item? Or any better suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use StackPanel

```
<TabItem ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView .../>
        <ListView .../>
        <ListView .../>
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```